# UIAlertController takes 15 seconds to display when adding text field

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertcontroller

I am having a new weird error. The project is super simple, just a UINavigationController with a root view controller.

My problem is that when the user clicks on a toolbar item, it calls the following code:

```
- (IBAction)configurePressed:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Capture Area"
                                                                             message:@"Enter the name of the area that is being captured."
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:nil];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                         handler:nil];

    UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Set"
                                                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                                          {
                                                              UITextField *captureArea = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
                                                              _captureArea = captureArea.text;
                                                          }];

    [alertController addAction:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:defaultAction];

    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Super simple right? Well, it takes 15 seconds to display the first time, then instantly on subsequent times. What is even weirder is that if I remove the line:

```
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:nil];
```

so there is no text input box, it displays instantaneous. I have also confirmed that it is being performed on the main thread.

UPDATE #1: New observation, when it is waiting to display, the main thread seems to be blocked. The AlertController is being displayed over an MKMapView.

UPDATE #2: This does not happen on the simulator.

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: What happens if you replace the handler of the second button with nil?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Just tried it but did not have any effect. Just edited the question with some more observation.

Comment: i have the same weird experience while using UIAlertController,not fixed yet

Comment: What stack/thread activity do you see when you break into debugger (few secs after ui appears to hang)?

Comment: The call to presentViewController is being performed on the main thread. Even tried wrapping the call in dispatch_async on the main thread to see if something funky wasn't happening. Still takes 15 seconds on the first call, instantaneous on all subsequent calls.

Comment: Just an observation, what happens if you pass a handler instead of nil?

Comment: No changes whether handler is nil or not.

Comment: I think I may be experiencing this problem in my swift code now, did you ever get to the bottom of it?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I ran across it when I was having the same issue.  My issue was solved when I noticed that my UIAlertController was trying to present on a background thread.  Not sure if this helps you given the 3 year age, but wanted to put a comment for others to possibly find.